# Batch files datetime

Tags: file, batch-file

I have written a batch file. It's my first one so I still suck at this.  What it does it copies a database backup file from a unc folder path and paste it to my local machine.  The file name changes every night with the datetime appended to it.
i.e file_backup_201306112210.bak

Below is what I have written in my batch file below

```
set datetimef=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
cmd /c echo F | xcopy "\\FileName\S$\DBs\file_backup_%datetimef%*.bak" "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\file_backup.bak"
```

The weird thing is that it does work every now and then but other days it fails.  I have tried to run it manually but still fails.

Can you please advise what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean 'fail's? Does it give an error message? If so, what?

Comment: Are you expecting that the date format will be the same on every execution? Are you using the same account to execute the batch file?

Comment: Why are you doing the `cmd /c ` - why not just `echo F | xcopy whatevr`

Comment: Well it does not give an error.  The Task scheduler says the Task completed but it did not copy.  So thats why I think the datetimef is incorrect.  Because I dont think the batch file cant find a file

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to `echo %datetimef%`.

Comment: Change your 2nd line to `echo F | xcopy "\\FileName\S$\DBs\file_backup_%datetimef%*.bak" "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\file_backup.bak" > c:\tmp\out 2>c:\tmp\err` - so if it fails then you will atleast find if some errors happened. Make sure whatever directory you are using instead of `c:\tmp` exists

Comment: Hi Alex - YEah the backup I create from database filename will always be same. and a Windows Scheduler runs the batch file using a admin account.  Its so frustrating because there are days it works and other days it doesnt.  And I know the file is there and I checked the correct paths.  I just cant figure it out

Comment: Hi user93353 - thats useful thanks.  there is nothing in my err file but in my out file I have the following. Does E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\file_backup.bak specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? F
\\Filename\S$\DBs\maxprod\file_backup_201306112210.bak - Can you please tell me what does that meen?  Thanks

Comment: I think that's the reason you have the echo F - xcopy is asking if `"E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\file_backup.bak"` is a directory name or a file name. `echo F` tells xcopy that it's a file name.

Comment: ok awesome. but then to you does everything look alright. I just cant see whats wrong.  Its making me crazy

Answer (score 2):

Try this and look in the log file to see:
A) if the server is accessible and
B) if a file exists that matches the filespec

```
@echo off
set datetimef=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
echo copying "file_backup_%datetimef%*.bak" on %date% at %time% >>"%userprofile%\desktop\log.txt"
dir "\\FileName\S$\DBs\file_backup_%datetimef%*.bak" >>"%userprofile%\desktop\log.txt" 2>&1

echo f|xcopy "\\FileName\S$\DBs\file_backup_%datetimef%*.bak" "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\file_backup.bak"
```

Comment: Ok Guys.  I am officially stupid.  What happens with the dateformat the backup is created last night and the batch file is searching for files with the date of the current date.  

So sometimes its works because the backup is sometime completed past midnight.

I just want to say thank you to all you guys for helping me.  I am really really grateful to all.  

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit confusing what exactly doesn't work, but there are several things you can do, for the date in your backup file name with date time:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: http://blog.g-ball.com/2010/08/26/year-month-day-date-batch-script/
:: Formatting the date into a YYYYMMDD format and setting it to the variable,  varTodaysDate
SET varYYYY=%DATE:~10,4%
SET varMM=%DATE:~4,2%
SET varDD=%DATE:~7,2%
SET varTodaysDate=%varYYYY%%varMM%%varDD%
```

If you have issues launching the batch, you might check if you are logged in when the batch is launched. Are you launching the batch file from a server management? If yes, you might check its configuration(Edit: Check with which account you run it, Run whether user is logged on or not option, and run the task, use the following user account: Administrator). If you have rights issues, I would recommand you CPAU, from http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/ . 
It will run the batch as administrator, download it and include it as following:

```
CPAU.exe -u 1 -p 1 -ex "cmd /c echo F | xcopy "\\FileName\S$\DBs\file_backup_%varTodaysDate%*.bak" "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\file_backup.bak"" -wait > log.txt 2> ./logerror.txt
```

If you are doing xcopy from shared drives, you have to replace CPAU.exe -u **username** -p **password**, but I wouldn't recommand it, its a security vulnerability if someone gets your batch file. What I could recommand as contra, would be WinSCP with scripts to run the same functionality and copy from one directory to another one.